# Collaborate while using postman ( Bearer Token )

Tags: postman, bearer-token

I have a quick question: 
If I had a collaboration with another individual and they used my API end points on their postman desktop app. Will that individual be able to see my bearer token if set up properly or would it be their own bearer token?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you export your postman collection and it has your bearer token in the headers of the request, person that imports it will have your bearer token.

Comment: If I don't actually export on my end than it wouldn't be my bearer token. If a bearer token was showing it would be the others correct?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand. Could you explain a bit more.

Comment: Hypothetically if person A wasn't to export on their own collection. Person B wouldn't be able to see person A Bearer Token unless Person A exported and Person B imported that JSON file.

Comment: If person B does not import it, he won't be able to see bearer token.

Comment: Also, if you are referring to workspace collaboration (adding team members to workspace). Easiest way to check what members of workspace see is to create test postman account and add it as team member and check for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Sessions` in Postman to set up a variable (Global, Environment or Collection) for your Bearer token, rather than hardcoding this in the Request.

If this is *only* set in the `Initial Value`, only you will see/be able to use that value and your team won't be able to see/use it. They will need to provide their own token value.

More information can be found here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JcSZtVwH69w

https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/environments_and_globals/Sessions/